# Multiple parameters for connection string

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, connection-string

I'm using python with sqlalchemy for access my sqlserver database (azure).

I want to access the data with charset=utf8 and with driver also.

This is my conenction string:

```
connect="mssql+pyodbc_mssql://<user>:<pass>@server/database?charset=utf8?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
```

So when the charset is the first - he doesn't take the driver and I can't connect.

And when the driver is first - I have problems with the unicode.

I tried to insert `;` or `,` between them instead of `?` but is doesn't work...

What is the right way to config multiple parameters in the connection string?

Please don't suggest to replace driver.

Thank you.

Comment: Is using `&` solved your problem (instead of `;` or `,`)

Answer (score 2):

The separator of parameters should be using `&` as in:

```
connect="mssql+pyodbc_mssql://<user>:<pass>@server/database?charset=utf8&driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
```